# Visibility converter binding in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following converter:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
...
```

I'm then using this in XAML as follows:

```
<Resources>
    <conv:MyConverter x:Key="MyValToVisibilityConverter" />
</Resources>

...

<CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" Content="Should not be visible" 
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource MyValToVisibilityConverter}}" 
...
```

This compiles and runs, and always shows the checkbox as visible.

Comment: Which of your XAML elements is named "Visibility"? Is there an error notice in your VS output window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the wrong parameter for the binding.

Right now, the bind target is an element named `Visibility`, which is most likely an error:

```
Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Visibility, Converter={...}}"
```

It should simply be

```
Visibility="{Binding Converter={...}}"
```